Expansion of arguments in commands
I have madethis command \RepNum{#1}{#2}. This command is created to indicate the number of times the argument #1 is repeated in the list #2, separated by commas.
\def\RepNum#1#2{%
    \begingroup
    \newcount\repnum % Counter for occurrences
    \repnum=0
    \def\SearchVar{#1}% Store the search argument
    \expandafter\repnumlist\expandafter#2,\relax,% Process the list
    \the\repnum % Output the count
    \endgroup
}

% Process each item in the list and count matches
\def\repnumlist#1,{%
    \ifx\relax#1 % End-of-list condition
    \else
        \edef\CurrVar{\unexpanded\expandafter{#1}}% Current variable
        \ifx\CurrVar\SearchVar % If the current variable matches the search
            \advance\repnum by 1
        \fi
        \expandafter\repnumlist % Recursion for the next variable
    \fi
}

When I use "normal" elements as argument #1 (e.g. x, x_{\tau}, {x_{tau}(a,b)}) the behaviour is correct. But, when I use something like \vec{x}, it doesn't reconize the elements in #2
Does anyone know what's wrong?

Semi unrelated: Why are you defining a new counter each time that macro is used? Note that Expl3 probably already have tools for this build in, see interface3.pdf

Can you please also show your usages? Also note that the \expandafter\repnumlist\expandafter#2 probably doesn't do what you want, simply use \repnumlist#2 there.

never do this \newcount\repnum % Counter for occurrences  that is allocating a new register each time you use the command, just allocate it once, in the preamble, and use it in the command.

This would be much easier to do in expl3 but if you want someone to debug the code as written please supply a test file that gives the error you are asking about, and state what output you expect from that file.

@daleif, I would like to use LaTeX or native TeX to do this. Many people have told me about the expl3 package, but I'm trying to avoid it.
@Skillmon, I have modified that sentence, but the behaviour is unchanged. I really don't know what \expandafter does exactly
@DavidCarlisle, the counter is nested inside a group. Will a new allocation be required even if used in that way?
I need to prepare a test file and, when I make it, I'll upload it

Do remember that expl3 is not a package anymore, it is included in the kernel, no packages needed. If you don't know tex programming already, I'd say it is a waste of time to not use expl3.

you can only ping one person per comment. yes, every time you use \RepNum, you are allocating a new count register. add \meaning\repnum after \the\repnum in your loop and you will see a different register is used each time \RepNum is used.

Add  \meaning\repnum after \the\repnum in your loop and you will in the .log-file and in the messages written to console/screen/shell see a different register is used each time \RepNum is used.


\edef\CurrVar{\unexpanded\expandafter{#1}}% with #1 = \vec{x} yields toplevel-expanding \vec so that \CurrVar in any case does not expand to the same as \SearchVar and thus \ifx-comparison of \CurrVar and \SearchVar leads to skipping the tokens forming the "true"-branch.

\repnumlist is to process a comma-delimited argument, so you need to ensure that curly braces surrounding an entire comma-delimited argument do not get stripped off/that stripping off a surrounding pair of curly braces doesn't matter.

You probably need to make sure that unmatched \unless/\if../\or/\else/\fi coming from user-provided macro arguments do not erroneously match up components of \if..-\else-\fi-expressions contained in the ⟨balanced text⟩s of your macro definitions.


Perhaps the following is a starting-point:
\newcount\repnum % Counter for occurrences

\long\def\gobblearg#1{}

\long\def\RepNum#1#2{%
  \begingroup
  \repnum=0
  \edef\SearchVar{\unexpanded{#1}}% Store the item to search
  \def\stopvalue{\relax}%
  \expandafter\repnumlist\expandafter{\expandafter{\expandafter}\expandafter}#2,\relax,% Recursively process the list
  \the\repnum % Output the count
  \endgroup
}

% Process each item in the list and count matches
\long\def\repnumlist#1,{%
  \edef\CurrVar{\unexpanded\expandafter{\gobblearg#1}}% Current comma-list-item
  \ifx\CurrVar\stopvalue
  \else
    \ifx\CurrVar\SearchVar % If the current comma-list item matches the item to search
      \advance\repnum by 1
    \fi
    \expandafter\repnumlist\expandafter{\expandafter{\expandafter}\expandafter}% Next iteration
  \fi
}

\def\list{z,{x_{tau}(a,b)},ghghj,,\fi,,\else,,,##1,##1,##1,{x_{tau}(a,b)},m,{x_{tau}(a,b)},hgjg,{x_{tau}(a,b)}}
\RepNum{{x_{tau}(a,b)}}{\list}

\RepNum{\else}{\list}

\RepNum{#1}{\list}

\def\list{z,\vec{x},ghghj,,\fi,,\else,,,##1,##1,##1,\vec{x},m,\vec{x},hgjg,\vec{x}}

\RepNum{\vec{x}}{\list}

\bye

Note:
Instead of prepending a pair of nested curly braces to the remaining comma-list for preventing the stripping off of surrounding curly braces with subsequent stuff in the stage of grabbing the comma-delimited argument, and after grabbing the comma-delimited argument  gobbling the tokens prepended for preventing brace-stripping, e.g., a single dot of category 12(other) or the like could be prepended and after grabbing the comma-delimited argument be gobbled. That way the \expandafter-chain would be shorter. Thus in practice that would be more efficient.
However, in the above example, such efficiency considerations are set aside and a pair of nested braces is used for illustrating an important aspect macro programming in TeX: The need of keeping track of possible brace-stripping:
In the case of the next token coming from the comma-list being a comma,  while grabbing the comma-delimited argument the entire comma-delimited argument consists only of the tokens prepended for preventing brace-stripping. I.e. consists only of a pair of nested braces whereof the outermost pair of braces gets stripped off in the course of grabbing the comma-delimited argument. If there was not an inner pair of braces, nothing would remain and thus the attempt at gobbling the tokens prepended for preventing brace-stripping would not gobble tokens prepended for preventing brace-stripping but would gobble tokens following the argument-delimiting comma that actually belong to the comma-list and that should not be gobbled.

There are a few errors in your code.
Here I propose code that's essentially your own algorithm, but using expl3 that has been in the LaTeX kernel for two years.
\documentclass{article}

\ExplSyntaxOn

\NewDocumentCommand{\RepNum}{mm}
 {% #1 are the tokens to count the appearances of in #2
  \serubi_repnum:nn {#1} {#2}
 }

\seq_new:N \l__serubi_repnum_seq
\int_new:N \l__serubi_repnum_int

\cs_new_protected:Nn \serubi_repnum:nn
 {
  \int_zero:N \l__serubi_repnum_int
  \seq_set_from_clist:Nn \l__serubi_repnum_seq {#2}
  \seq_map_inline:Nn \l__serubi_repnum_seq
   {
    \tl_if_eq:nnT {##1}{#1} { \int_incr:N \l__serubi_repnum_int }
   }
  \int_to_arabic:n { \l__serubi_repnum_int }
 }

\ExplSyntaxOff

\begin{document}

\RepNum{x}{x,y,x,x} (should be 3)

\RepNum{x}{z,z,w} (should be 0)

% here items in the second argument should be braced
\RepNum{x_{\tau}(a,b)}{{x_{\tau}(a,b)},{x_{\tau}(c)},{x_{\tau}(a,b)}} (should be 2)

\RepNum{\vec{x}}{\vec{x},\vec{x},\vec{y},\vec{x},\vec{y}} (should be 3)

\end{document}


